# How to launch WebXR from an HTML button callback?

Tags: aframe

**Problem**

I want to launch an a-frame based WebXR environment from an HTML button's callback. I'll be adding a-entity's later from JavaScript.

**Environment**

Running a-frame 1.0.4 on Chrome Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) beta (64-bit) on Windows 10.

**What I've tried**

I populated the body with an HTML button ahead of an a-scene with an a-plane in my html, but the html button isn't clickable:

```
<body>
<button id="startButton" onclick="onButtonClicked()">START</button>
<a-scene>
    <a-plane id="plane1" position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" wireframe="false"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
</body>
```

I populated the body with just an HTML button, and then inserted WebXR innerHTML from the button callback. That seems to work somewhat. After pressing the html button, the VR button appears, but the canvas goes black when I push the VR button. I get the same behavior when using JavaScript to dynamically add the WebXR elements instead of innerHTML.

The best solution so far has been to implement the rendering pipeline (requestSession(), requestReferenceSpace(), drawScene(), etc.), but I'm struggling to get the drawScene() properly implemented.

**Question**:

Is there a way to simply launch the existing WebXR pipeline so I don't have to implement the rendering pipeline myself?

Maybe something like this:

```
navigator.xr.initXR()
```

or

```
navigator.xr.requestSession('immersive-vr').then(navigator.xr.onSessionStarted);
```

Comment: Without a link with a simple runnable example to reproduce it will be hard to help you. [Glitch is a good option](https://glitch.com/~aframe)

Comment: [Here's a glitch project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/plausible-abundant-magnosaurus) showing what I am trying do.

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame comes with a built-in enter VR button that you can costumize via the [vr-mode-ui component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/vr-mode-ui.html#specifying-a-custom-enter-vr-button)

```
<a-scene
  vr-mode-ui="enterVRButton: #myEnterVRButton; enterARButton: #myEnterARButton">
  <!-- Style the button with images or whatever. -->
  <a id="myEnterVRButton" href="#"></a>
  <a id="myEnterARButton" href="#"></a>
</a-scene>
```

Example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fluoridated-ruby-whip?path=index.html%3A16%3A105

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. The presence of the a-scene tag prevents the HTML button from working.

Comment: It works for me. You just need to style accordingly. See answer for link to example.

Comment: I tried to make my original post as simple as possible, but I see now that I need to elaborate a little.